# Postgres: Many to many joins creates double output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've recently added a many to many JOIN to one of my queries to add a "tag" functionality. The many to many works great, however, it's now causing a previously working part of the query to output records twice.

```
          SELECT v.* 
          FROM "Server" AS s 
            JOIN "Vote" AS v ON (s.id = v."serverId")
            JOIN "_ServerToTag" st ON (s.id = st."A") 
          OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25;
 id  |        createdAt        | authorId | serverId 
-----+-------------------------+----------+----------
 190 | 2020-12-23 15:47:25.476 |     6667 |        3
 190 | 2020-12-23 15:47:25.476 |     6667 |        3
 194 | 2020-12-21 15:47:25.476 |     6667 |        3
 194 | 2020-12-21 15:47:25.476 |     6667 |        3
```

In the example above:

- `Server` is my main table which contains a bunch of entries. Think of it as Reddit Posts, they have a title, content and use the `Vote` table to count "upvotes".

```
 id |             title             
----+-------------------------------
  3 | test server 3
```

- `Votes` is a really simple table, it contains a timestamp of the "upvote", who created it, and the `Server.id` it is assigned to.
- `_ServerToTag` is a table that contains two columns `A` and `B`. It connects `Server` to another table which contains `Tags`.

```
 A | B 
---+---
 3 | 1
 3 | 2
```

The above is a much-simplified query, in reality, I am `sum`ing the outcome of the query to get a `number` total of Votes.

The desired outcome would be that the results are not duplicated:

```
 id  |        createdAt        | authorId | serverId 
-----+-------------------------+----------+----------
 190 | 2020-12-23 15:47:25.476 |     6667 |        3
 194 | 2020-12-21 15:47:25.476 |     6667 |        3
```

I'm really unsure why this is even happening so I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

`DISTINCT` works if I want to query the `Vote` table. But not in more complex queries. In my case it would look something more like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, sum(case WHEN v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND v."createdAt" < '2021-01-01'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "voteCount", 
          FROM "Server" AS s 
            LEFT JOIN "Vote" AS v ON (s.id = "serverId")
            LEFT JOIN "_ServerToTag" st ON (s.id = st."A");
 id |             title             | voteCount 
----+-------------------------------+-----------
  3 | test server 3                 |         4
```

In the above, I only need the `voteCount` column to be DISTINCT.

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, sum(DISTINCT case WHEN v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND v."createdAt" < '2021-01-01'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "voteCount", 
          FROM "Server" AS s 
            LEFT JOIN "Vote" AS v ON (s.id = "serverId")
            LEFT JOIN "_ServerToTag" st ON (s.id = st."A");
 id |             title             | voteCount 
----+-------------------------------+-----------
  3 | test server 3                 |         1
```

The above kind of works, but it seems to only count one vote even if there are multiple.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This is expected behavior when you add additional joins.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added samples from the other two tables. I didn't realise this was expected behavior, how should I change my query to remove the duplicate entries?

Comment: Don't forget to state the *goal* of your query. (do you only want `server`.* , maybe with some associated count?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I went and asked a friend for help after not really being able to fix my problem with the answers I received.

I think my query was just too complex and confusing and I was suggested to use subqueries to make it less complicated and easier to manage.

My query now looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.id
,   s.title
,   COALESCE(v."VOTES", 0) AS "voteCount" 
FROM "Server" AS s
    -- Join tags
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            st."A"
        ,   json_agg(
                        json_build_object(
                            'id', 
                            t.id, 
                            'tagName', 
                            t."tagName"
                        )
                    ) as "tagsArray"
        FROM
            "_ServerToTag" AS st
        INNER JOIN
            "Tag" AS t
        ON
            t.id = st."B"
        GROUP BY
            st."A"
    ) AS tag
    ON
        tag."A" = s.id
    -- Count votes
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            "serverId"
        ,   COUNT(*) AS "VOTES" 
        FROM 
            "Vote" as v 
        WHERE 
            v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND 
            v."createdAt" <  '2021-01-01' 
        GROUP BY "serverId"
    ) as v 
    ON 
        s.id = v."serverId"
    OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25;
```

This works exactly the same way but by selecting what I need directly in the joins it's more readable and I have more control over the data I get back.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is that you added the join to `_ServerToTag`. Because there are multiple rows in `_ServerToTag` for each row in `Server` the query returns multiple rows for each server, one for each matching row in `_ServerToTag`.

It appears that `_ServerToTag` was adde to the query so it will only include servers which have tags. If that's your intent you can use:

```
SELECT v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId, COUNT(DISTINCT v.createdAt) AS TOTAL_VOTES
  FROM "Server" AS s 
  INNER JOIN "Vote" AS v
    ON s.id = v."serverId"
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT "A" FROM "_ServerToTag") st
    ON s.id = st."A"
  WHERE v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND
        v."createdAt" < '2021-01-01'
  GROUP BY v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId
  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25
```

or

```
SELECT v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId, COUNT(DISTINCT v.createdAt) AS TOTAL_VOTES
  FROM "Server" AS s 
  INNER JOIN "Vote" AS v
    ON s.id = v."serverId"
  WHERE v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND
        v."createdAt" < '2021-01-01' AND
        s.id IN (SELECT "A" FROM "_ServerToTag")
  GROUP BY v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId
  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25
```

which may communicate the intent of the query a bit better.

### EDIT

If you want to be able to count entries which have no votes you'll need to use an outer join to pull in the (potentially non-existent) votes and then use a CASE expression to only count votes if they exist:

```
SELECT s.id, v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId,
       CASE
         WHEN v.id IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT v.createdAt)
       END AS TOTAL_VOTES
  FROM "Server" AS s 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Vote" AS v
    ON s.id = v."serverId"
  WHERE v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND
        v."createdAt" < '2021-01-01' AND
        s.id IN (SELECT "A" FROM "_ServerToTag")
  GROUP BY s.id, v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId
  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25
```

You may not actually need that though - you may be able to get away with

```
SELECT s.id, v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId,
       COUNT(DISTINCT v.createdAt) AS TOTAL_VOTES
  FROM "Server" AS s 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Vote" AS v
    ON s.id = v."serverId"
  WHERE v."createdAt" >= '2020-12-01' AND
        v."createdAt" < '2021-01-01' AND
        s.id IN (SELECT "A" FROM "_ServerToTag")
  GROUP BY s.id, v.id, v.authorId, v.serverId
  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25
```

Comment: So the trick seems to be with `Count`. it works great and solves the problem. Unfortunately if I then `WHERE` to only count `Vote`s that have been cast in a certain timeperiod, I won't be able to return entries that have no Votes. Which was my original reason to use `SUM`

Comment: @Eight - added OUTER JOIN examples